# Determine smallest changes in Treeview

Tags: algorithm, treeview, compare

I have a treeview in which a user can move, delete subtrees, nodes and create nodes.

I do not want to persist every single action at once but the user can say "apply my changes". Therefore I need to compare the new tree with the old tree and - most important - determine the smallest set of operations to build the new tree. What's a approach to this problem?

I am using ASP.NET/C# but the question is not really tight to that technology.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you just record the changes user makes as he makes them and then persist them in one go?

Comment: of course I can dot that but I want to prevent unneccesary changes (e.g. the user is just playing around in the tree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches to your problem. You could just cache all the user's editing actions and then apply them in a batch update. This addresses the "not at once" part of your goals.

If you want to replace the user actions with an optimal set of actions that produces the same result (for some definition of "optimal"), this is, in general, a very difficult problem to solve. The best known algorithm, I believe, is based on something called the "editing distance between trees" and is described in a [technical report by Zhang and Shasha](http://ia600301.us.archive.org/11/items/oneditingdistanc00zhan/oneditingdistanc00zhan.pdf). Be warned that this is very dense reading. There's a much more readable article [here](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/niagara/papers/xdiff.pdf) for finding an optimal editing script to change one XML document into another. It's based on first converting the XML into trees and working on them, so the core algorithms may be directly applicable to your problem. It even comes with pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

Like svick says, the best option is to record all changes and apply them when the user click the "Apply" button.

The only thing that could be improved, is that when a user makes a change, you can check in the record whether there is a change which is negated by this new change. In that case one or more entries can be deleted. 
Examples I could think of are

- moving a node for the second time negates the first movement
- deleting a recently created node and vice versa. In this case the new record entry should also be removed.
- deleting a node and creating another node(or equally sized subtrees) can be replaced by a movement

This doesn't provide the *optimal* solution with the least amount of record entries, but  presumably the goal is to speed up applying the changes, which is accomplished. You could detect other kinds of sequences of manipulations which can be simplified, but that's probably not worth it. Detecting such complex manipulation sequences will probably be too costly to be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that consolidating the operations is the best option available and in my case I couldn't think of a scenario where a non optimal solution would be generated. If someone is actually interested I have shared my consolidation code here:

```
 public class TreeOperationConsolidator : ITreeOperationConsolidator
{
    public IEnumerable<ITreeOperation> ConsolidateOperations(IEnumerable<ITreeOperation> operations)
    {
        List<ITreeOperation> result = new List<ITreeOperation>();
        foreach (var op in operations)
        {
            if (op.Operation == OperationType.Move)
            {
                ConsolidateMoveOperation(op, operations, result);
            }
            else if (op.Operation == OperationType.Rename)
            {
                ConsolidateRenameOperation(op, operations, result);
            }
            else if (op.Operation == OperationType.Create)
            {
                ConsolidateCreateOperation(op, operations, result);
            }
            else if (op.Operation == OperationType.Delete)
            {
                ConsolidateDeleteOperation(op, operations, result);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void ConsolidateDeleteOperation(ITreeOperation op, IEnumerable<ITreeOperation> operations, List<ITreeOperation> result)
    {
        bool newlyCreated = result.Any(o => o.SourceId == op.SourceId && o.Operation == OperationType.Create);

        result.RemoveAll(o => o.SourceId == op.SourceId);

        var children = (from o in result
                        where
                            (o.Operation == OperationType.Move && o.DestId == op.SourceId)
                            || (o.Operation == OperationType.Create && o.DestId == op.SourceId)
                        select o).ToList();

        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            result.Remove(child);
            ConsolidateDeleteOperation(new TreeOperation { Operation = OperationType.Temp, SourceId = child.SourceId }, operations, result);
        }

        if (newlyCreated == false && op.Operation != OperationType.Temp)
            result.Add(op);
    }

    private void ConsolidateCreateOperation(ITreeOperation op, IEnumerable<ITreeOperation> operations, List<ITreeOperation> result)
    {
        result.Add(op);
    }

    private void ConsolidateRenameOperation(ITreeOperation op, IEnumerable<ITreeOperation> operations, List<ITreeOperation> result)
    {
        var createOperation = result.FirstOrDefault(o => o.SourceId == op.SourceId && o.Operation == OperationType.Create);
        if (createOperation == null)
        {
            var renameOp = result.FirstOrDefault(o => o.SourceId == op.SourceId && o.Operation == op.Operation);
            if (renameOp != null)
            {
                result.Remove(renameOp);
            }
            result.Add(op);
        }
        else
        {
            createOperation.Argument = op.Argument;
        }
    }

    protected void ConsolidateMoveOperation(ITreeOperation op, IEnumerable<ITreeOperation> operations, List<ITreeOperation> result)
    {
        var createOperation = result.FirstOrDefault(o => o.SourceId == op.SourceId && o.Operation == OperationType.Create);
        if (createOperation == null)
        {
            var moveOp = result.FirstOrDefault(o => o.SourceId == op.SourceId && o.Operation == op.Operation);
            if (moveOp != null)
            {
                result.Remove(moveOp);
            }
            result.Add(op);
        }
        else
        {
            createOperation.DestId = op.DestId;
        }
    }
}

public class TreeOperation : ITreeOperation
{
    public string Argument { get; set; }

    public OperationType Operation { get; set; }

    public string SourceId { get; set; }

    public string DestId { get; set; }
}

public enum OperationType
{
    Move,
    Rename,
    Create,
    Delete,
    Temp
}

public interface ITreeOperationConsolidator
{
    IEnumerable<ITreeOperation> ConsolidateOperations(IEnumerable<ITreeOperation> operations);
}

public interface ITreeOperation
{
    string Argument { get; set; }

    OperationType Operation { get; set; }

    string SourceId { get; set; }

    string DestId { get; set; }
}
```

So what you need to do is to track all user actions in the tree (i.e. save instances of ITreeOperation in the session (or somewhere else). Before applying all changes make sure to call `IEnumerable<ITreeOperation> ConsolidateOperations(IEnumerable<ITreeOperation> operations)`.